# NestWhile implementation of pushDown operation does not return expected outcome. What am I missing?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

An input (in this example) consists of a list {g, v} containing

- a heap g implemented as a labelled graph g, with labels displayed in blue, vertices in red.
- a vertex v

The function pushDown will push down a (blue) label in a labelled graph that is almost a heap (bar the label to be pushed down).
The result is a heap-structure.

Hourglass-shaped nodes in graph are produced by vf

```
    vf[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := 
  Block[{xmin = xc - w, xmax = xc + w, ymin = yc - h, ymax = yc + h}, 
   Polygon[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}]];
```

vertexLabel returns the label of a vertex

```
vertexLabel[g_, v_] := AnnotationValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels]
```

vertexLabelsOnSublist returns the labels on a sublist of VertexList

```
vertexLabelsOnSublist[g_, lis_] := vertexLabel[g, #] & /@ lis
```

paintBlue ensures that a chosen label in the graph is displayed in blue

```
paintBlue[x_] := Style[x, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]
```

bareLabels removes the blue colour from each label in a list

```
bareLabels[labelList_] := #[[1]] & /@ labelList
```

blueLabelsOnSublist produces the blue labels on a sublist of vertices
(intended to be the list of successor (or list of predecessors) of a vertex)

```
    blueLabelsOnSublist[g_, vertexSublist_] := #[[1]][[2]] & /@ 
  vertexLabelsOnSublist[g, vertexSublist]
```

The following are self-explanatory:

```
predecessorVertices[g_, v_] := Rest[VertexInComponent[g, v, 1]]

predecessorLabels[g_, v_] := 
 vertexLabelsOnSublist[g, predecessorVertices[g, v]]

predecessorBlueLabels[g_, v_] := 
 blueLabelsOnSublist[g, predecessorVertices[g, v]]
```

swapDown executes without checking that predecessors actually exist. This check is by pushDown which calls swapDown repeatedly using NestWhile (as long as predecessors exists and labels are out of order)

```
swapDown[{state_, v_}] :=
 Module[{maxLabel, maxPredecessor},
  maxLabel = {}; maxPredecessor = {};
  maxLabel = paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
      predecessorBlueLabels[state, v]   ]]]; 
  maxPredecessor = 
   Select[predecessorVertices[state, v], 
     blueLabelsOnSublist[state, {#}][[1]] == 
       paintBlue[Max[bareLabels[
          predecessorBlueLabels[state, v]      ]]] &] [[1]] ;
  {SetProperty[state, 
    VertexLabels -> {v -> 
       Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, v}, VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
         maxLabel}, {Before, After}], 
      maxPredecessor -> 
       Placed[{AnnotationValue[{state, maxPredecessor }, 
            VertexLabels][[1]][[1]], 
         AnnotationValue[{state, v}, 
            VertexLabels][[1]][[2]]}, {Before, After}]}], 
   maxPredecessor }]
```

The problem arises with pushDown (using the NestWhile):

```
pushDown[{state_, v_}] := 
 NestWhile[swapDown[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] &, {state, v}, 
  predecessorVertices[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & != {} && 
     bareLabels[blueLabelsOnSublist[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}]][[1]] & < 
   Max[bareLabels[
     predecessorBlueLabels[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &   ]]]
```

Consider a heap (for which the odd display results from having copied the output of another function. When copied in a notebook the heap displays properly):

testState = !(*
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"Graph", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4"}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"DirectedEdge", "[",
RowBox[{"2", ",", "4"}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"DirectedEdge", "[",
RowBox[{"3", ",", "4"}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"DirectedEdge", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "2"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"ImageSize", ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"240", ",", "240"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"VertexCoordinates", ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"0.`", ",",  RowBox[{"-", "2.`"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"0.`", ",",  RowBox[{"-", "1.`"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"1.`", ",",  RowBox[{"-", "1.`"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"1.`", ",", "0.`"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"VertexLabels", ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"4", ",",
RowBox[{"Placed", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"4", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"4", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"Before", ",", "After"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"2", ",",
RowBox[{"Placed", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"2", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"3", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"Before", ",", "After"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",",
RowBox[{"Placed", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"2", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"Before", ",", "After"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"3", ",",
RowBox[{"Placed", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"3", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Style", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",",
RowBox[{"RGBColor", "[",
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"Before", ",", "After"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}],
"]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"VertexShapeFunction", ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[", "vf", "]"}]}], "]"}], ",",
RowBox[{"Rule", "[",
RowBox[{"VertexWeight", ",",
RowBox[{"List", "[",
RowBox[{"1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}],
"]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm])

Re-label to root to the zero value (so it becomes a label to be pushdown to restore the heap structure)

```
    testState = 
 SetProperty[testState, 
  VertexLabels -> {4 -> 
     Placed[List[Style[4, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
       Style[0, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]], List[Before, After]]}]
```

The conditions in pushDown return True as expected:

```
predecessorVertices[testState, 4] != {}
```

returns True

```
bareLabels[blueLabelsOnSublist[testState, {4}]][[1]] < 
 Max[bareLabels[
   predecessorBlueLabels[testState, 4]]]
```

returns True

```
swapDown[{testState, 4}]
```

produces the expected result in which the 0 value is swapped down, exchanged with the max label below it (label 3)

[image]

A call to

```
pushDown[{testState, 4}]
```

produces the original input, i.e. it does not push down the label 0.

I checked

```
Trace[pushDown[{testState, 4}]]
```

It seems that the condition in NestWhile does not get the necessary arguments passed
to #[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raiq7.png)] and #[[2]]

I may be missing something trivial. Where does the issue arise?

Comment: First, testState does not evaluate. Then, the test-functions inside  pushDown do not receive an argument. Write it: `pushDown[{state_, v_}] := 
 NestWhile[
  swapDown[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] &, {state, 
   v}, (predecessorVertices[#[[1]], #[[2]]] != {} && 
     bareLabels[blueLabelsOnSublist[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}]][[1]] < 
      Max[bareLabels[predecessorBlueLabels[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]]) &]`

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: You need to put the `&` at the ens of the entire test expression, not in-between. So e.g. `#1&==2 && test[#2[[1]]&]` should be `#1==2 && test[#2[[1]]] &`.

Comment: @Daniel Huber that works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks!